# ASP.NET MVC moq returns empty list

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I'm using moq framework to test my MVC application. I've added a generic repository and unit of work class. When I run the test of my controller it fails because the mock returns an empty list (size 0) even though I've added two elements. Here is my test:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void Index()
        {
            var repMock = new Mock<IFakultetRepository<Students>>();
            var students = new List<Students>();
            students.Add(new Students() { BI = "10011", Ime = "Pera", Prezime = "Peric", Adresa = "Ulica1", Grad = "Grad1"});
            students.Add(new Students() { BI = "20011", Ime = "Marko", Prezime = "Markovic", Adresa = "Ulica2", Grad = "Grad2" });

            repMock.Setup(x => x.GetEntities()).Returns(students.ToPagedList(1, 5));

            StudentsController controller = new StudentsController(repMock.Object);
            ViewResult result = controller.Index("", "test", "test", 1) as ViewResult;
            var listResult = result.ViewData.Model as PagedList<Students>;
            var list = listResult.ToList();

            Assert.AreEqual(2, list.Count);
}
```

Here is my generic repository which implements my generic repository interface:

```
public class FakultetRepository<TEntity> : IFakultetRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class 
    {
        internal FakultetEntities context;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

        public FakultetRepository(FakultetEntities context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetEntities()
        {
            return dbSet.ToList();
        }

        public virtual TEntity GetEntityById(object id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(id);
        }

        public virtual TEntity GetEntityById(string id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(id);
        }

        public virtual TEntity GetEntityById(object[] id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(id);
        }

        public virtual void InsertEntity(TEntity entity)
        {
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public virtual void DeleteEntity(object id)
        {
            TEntity entity = dbSet.Find(id);
            DeleteEntity(entity);
        }

        public virtual void DeleteEntity(TEntity entity)
        {
            if(context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                dbSet.Attach(entity);
            }
            dbSet.Remove(entity);
        }

        public virtual void UpdateEntity(TEntity entity)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entity);
            context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
```

In controller I have a constructor which initializes the unit of work and sets its repository:

```
public StudentsController(IFakultetRepository<Students> studentRepository)
        {
            this.unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
            this.unitOfWork.StudentsRepository = studentRepository;
        }
```

And here is the controller method I'm testing:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string search, int? page)
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.BISortParm = sortOrder == "BI" ? "bi_desc" : "BI";
            ViewBag.CitySortParm = sortOrder == "city" ? "city_desc" : "city";

            if (search != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                search = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = search;


            var students = from s in unitOfWork.StudentsRepository.GetEntities()
                           select s;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                students = students.Where(s => s.Prezime.Contains(search)
                                       || s.Ime.Contains(search)
                                       || s.BI.Contains(search));
            }

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.Prezime);
                    break;
                case "BI":
                    students = students.OrderBy(s => s.BI);
                    break;
                case "bi_desc":
                    students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.BI);
                    break;
                case "city":
                    students = students.OrderBy(s => s.Grad);
                    break;
                case "city_desc":
                    students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.Grad);
                    break;
                default:
                    students = students.OrderBy(s => s.Prezime);
                    break;
            }
            int pageSize = 10;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View("Index", students.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
```

Comment: Most likely `students.ToPagedList(1, 5)` returns the empty list which is what you observer. My guess is that you are returning page 5 where the page size is 1 and with two elements there is nothing to show at page 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating two students:

```
students.Add(new Students() 
{ 
    BI = "10011", Ime = "Pera", 
    Prezime = "Peric", Adresa = "Ulica1", 
    Grad = "Grad1"
});

students.Add(new Students() 
{ 
    BI = "20011", Ime = "Marko",
    Prezime = "Markovic", Adresa = "Ulica2", 
    Grad = "Grad2" 
});
```

You are calling this controller method:

```
Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string search, int? page)
```

With these values:

```
result = controller.Index("", "test", "test", 1) as ViewResult;
```

In the controller method you apply a filter to the results returned from the call to `GetEntities()`

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
{
      students = students.Where(s => s.Prezime.Contains(search)
                                  || s.Ime.Contains(search)
                                  || s.BI.Contains(search));   
 }
```

As we saw above, the value of `search` is "test"

So, assuming the mock has been invoked and has returned the students the reason you are seeing no values returned in your unit test is

> that they have been removed by the filter.

Comment: Oh man, I've been applying a search filter all along, removed it and it works fine. Can't believe I've missed that, what a stupid mistake, need to take a break now. :) Thanks!

Comment: No problem - I've been wanting to use the spoiler tag for ages :)

Answer (score 0):

Also using an IList instead of List it will do the trick.

Note that you must display properties in the view.

```
[Required]
    public IList<ListProductViewModel> Products { get; set; }

 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Products.Count(); i++)
  {
  <tr id=@Model.Products[i].Id>
    <td>@(rowNo++).</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Products[i].Name)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Products[i].Description)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Products[i].Price)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Products[i].Tax)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Products[i].MeasureUnit)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Products[i].Currency)</td>
    <td>@Html.NumberTextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.Products[i].Quantity)</td>
    <td>@Html.CheckBoxBoxFor(modelItem => Model.Products[i].IsSelected)</td>
  </tr>
  }
```

Comment: Copy-paste my code won't work because i'm using some html helpers that extend some of the classic MVC helpers